# How to write on hard disk with bios interrupt 13h

Tags: assembly, bootloader, bootstrapping, bios

I want to copy my boot loader to first sector(512) of hard disk within itself (I should use bios interrupt 13h) and I found this code:

```
mov bx, buffer1       ; set BX to the address (not the value) of BlahBlah 
mov ah,03h            ;When ah=, int13 reads a disk sector
mov al,5              ;Al is how many sectors to read

mov cl,0              ;Sector Id
mov dh,0              ;Head
mov dl,80h            ;Drive (0 is floppy)
mov cx,512            ;One sector /2   

mov ah, 0x3           ; set function 2h
int 0x13
```

bu it does not work!

Comment: Copy pasta code is never a good way of doing things. You should learn some assembler and try to understand _why_ your code doesn't work. Then you can attempt to solve it yourself and come here if you get stuck.

Comment: Have you noticed that the comment says function 2h ? but it actually moves 0x3 to ah

Comment: i know what code is doing! i change it actually (3h is an example)! what i don't know is that why it is not working!

Comment: Did you load the segment register with the appropriate segment portion of the buffer's address? Did you check with the BIOS reference (e.g. Ralf Brown's Interrupt List) that you're using this BIOS function correctly (setting other registers to correct values)?

Comment: start by learning to read from a working disk first, get used to the bios calls, then you will know what to do when it is time to write.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is very messy. In order to properly use `int 13h` with `AH = 3`, you need to also set `ES` (the segment in which `BX` resides, e.g. `ES:BX` is the address of the buffer which should be read and written to the hard disk), and `CX` to a combination of the cylinder and sector number (`cylinder = CL[7:6] || CH`, `sector = CL[5:0]`).

Assuming that you want to write one sector (512 bytes) from the physical address `5000h` to CHS 0:0:1 on hard disk 0, your code would look something like this :

```
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax    ; ES <- 0
mov cx, 1     ; cylinder 0, sector 1
mov dx, 0080h ; DH = 0 (head), drive = 80h (0th hard disk)
mov bx, 5000h ; segment offset of the buffer
mov ax, 0301h ; AH = 03 (disk write), AL = 01 (number of sectors to write)
int 13h
```

You should also remember to check whether the Carry Flag has been set after executing the interrupt. It will be clear if the function has been executed properly. If it's set, then the `AH` register will contain an error code.

Answer (score 2):

BIOS functions have input parameters. If you don't get all of the input parameters right, the BIOS function isn't able to guess what you meant. For the BIOS function you're using have a look at: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0608.htm

As far as I can tell, you're missing sane values for both CH and ES, so the BIOS can write data from a completely different address to a completely different sector. Also note that CL is the lowest half of the CX register - there's no point loading a value into CL and then overwriting it by loading something into CX.

BIOS functions return values too. In your case the BIOS may be returning a status code that tells you what went wrong, and because you don't check you don't know if anything went wrong or what it was if it did.