# String buffer in assembly and BIOS Inturrupts

Tags: string, assembly, buffer, sector

I am trying to write a string into sector 2 of a hard-disk. It seems to be failing.  Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax    
mov cx, 1     
mov dx, 0080h 
mov bx, NameString 
mov ax, 0301h 
int 13h

NameString db 'string', 0
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? How is it failing?

Comment: 1) "I am trying to write a string into sector 2 of a hard-disk"

Comment: 2) By not writing to the disk...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address of NameString needs to be in es:bx but you're zeroing es.  Load es correctly and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're attempting to write to sector 1, not sector 2.

An insane thing to try to do at this stage of the game, IMO, but I suppose it's a "fake" hard drive so you probably won't break anything critical... I hope...

Best,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with writing on the hard-disk, but can this be usefull to you? 
[How to write on hard disk with bios interrupt 13h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057670/how-to-write-on-hard-disk-with-bios-interrupt-13h)

Comment: I did take a look at that, but I don't know how to structure the NameString so it actually works